# I created a window using C++and WinAPI and used the UpdateLayeredWindow function, but I cannot understand what controls the alpha of the window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

The code used UpdateLayeredWindow is

```
HDC hdc = GetWindowDC(hWnd);
int width = 400;
int height = 300;
HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, width, height);

HDC hdcMem = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
SelectObject(hdcMem, hBitmap);


BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.BlendFlags = 0;
blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255; 

RECT rcClient;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &rcClient);
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(128, 128, 128));
FillRect(hdcMem, &rcClient,brush);
POINT ptDst = { 0, 0 };
SIZE sizeWnd = { width, height };
POINT ptSrc = { 0, 0 };
UpdateLayeredWindow(hWnd, hdc, NULL, &sizeWnd, hdcMem, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);

// 释放资源
DeleteDC(hdcMem);
DeleteObject(hBitmap);
ReleaseDC(hWnd, hdc);
```

In my opinion, this window should be completely opaque, with a SourceConstantAlpha value of 255 for blend, but in reality, it is semi transparent. It looks like this
[image]
But when i use RGB(255, 255, 255),it's completely opaque.And When i use RGB(0, 0, 0),it's compltely transparent.
It seems that the RGB of brush affects transparency.I can't understand how the aplha blend.

I tried to modify RGB and SourceConstantAlpha.Both of them have an impact on the alpha value.And I have consulted the documentation for the WinAPI.The formular is Dst.Alpha = Src.Alpha + (1 - Src.Alpha) * Dst.Alpha. It seems that when SourceConstantAlpha is 255,the window should be complelely opaque,but it's not.This is very confusing for me.I want to know how the alpha blend.

Comment: `UpdateLayeredWindow()` is best used when you have a bitmap image representing your entire window. That doesn't seem to be the case here. If all you want is a transparent color or whole-window translucency on a standard window, `SetLayeredWindowAttributes()` is much simpler to use.

Comment: You're filling your source bitmap using GDI, but GDI doesn't support alpha. If you want to go that route you need a full 32 bit source bitmap. You can either use Gdiplus, which does support alpha, or create the bitmap with `CreateDIBSection` which gives you a pointer to the bitmap bits so you can manipulate them directly. Remember also that your bitmap needs to use pre-multiplied alpha.

Comment: @JonathanPotter But why does brush's color affect alpha

Comment: Hi, Aesma. Any ideas on my answer?

Answer (score 0):

This flag is set when the bitmap has an Alpha channel (that is, per-pixel alpha). Note that the APIs use premultiplied alpha, which means that the red, green and blue channel values in the bitmap must be **premultiplied** with the alpha channel value. For example, if the alpha channel value is x, the red, green and blue channels must be multiplied by x and divided by 0xff prior to the call.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-blendfunction

That's why `RGB(0,0,0)` made a completely transparent window.

It is recommended to use `SetLayeredWindowAttributes`, which strictly follows the alpha value used to describe the opacity of the layered window.
When bAlpha is 0, the window is completely transparent. When bAlpha is 255, the window is opaque.

Answer (score 0):

If simply filling the surface is enough for you, you can create premultiplied RGBA brush like this:

```
HBRUSH CreateSolidBrushEx (COLORREF color, unsigned char alpha) {
    BITMAPINFO bi;

    bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof bi.bmiHeader;
    bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = 1u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = 1u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = 0u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biXPelsPerMeter = 0u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biYPelsPerMeter = 0u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biClrUsed = 0u;
    bi.bmiHeader.biClrImportant = 0u;

    bi.bmiColors[0].rgbBlue     = MulDiv (GetBValue (color), alpha, 0xFFu);
    bi.bmiColors[0].rgbGreen    = MulDiv (GetGValue (color), alpha, 0xFFu);
    bi.bmiColors[0].rgbRed      = MulDiv (GetRValue (color), alpha, 0xFFu);
    bi.bmiColors[0].rgbReserved = alpha;

    return CreateDIBPatternBrushPt (&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
};
```

But note that using other GDI APIs to draw on top of that will **NOT** properly blend, but rather **overwrite** the alpha channel, and you'll end up with more weird artifacts.

To properly blend operations, you'll need to draw every single thing into its own fresh compatible bitmap, and combine them using [AlphaBlend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-alphablend) function. This will of course eat a lot of memory and won't be exactly super fast if done on larger scale.

Answer (score 0):

The description for [SourceConstantAlpha](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-blendfunction#members) says:

> The SourceConstantAlpha value is combined with any per-pixel alpha values in the source bitmap. ... Set the SourceConstantAlpha value to 255 (opaque) when you only want to use per-pixel alpha values.

Your bitmap is created with GDI operations that don't promise anything when it comes to setting the alpha channel in the individual pixels.

```cpp
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(128, 128, 128));
FillRect(hdcMem, &rcClient,brush);
```

The FillRect might not touch the alpha channel at all.  Or it might copy the alpha from the brush.  But you don't have any control over what that value is when you use CreateSolidBrush.

So you have uninitialized values in the alpha slot for each pixel (or they've been initialize to a value you don't control).  The blend function relies on those values.  Chances are, they're not 255.

You'll need a way to set the per-pixel alphas in the memory bitmap.